Facebook Like Button in website has no effect in pages
I have a facebook page and my own domain.
In my page on my own domain www.example.com, I want to have a facebook like button that is actually making people like my facebook page (www.facebook.com/example).
I got the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v21.0&appId=MY_APP_ID"></script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/example"  data-width="" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="" data-share="false" data-show-faces="true"></div>

This used to work (years ago, I honestly don't know when it stopped working).
Now it seems to have no effect at all. When I install it in my site, the button takes time to load and shows the correct like count that I can see in the fb page. However, when I click on it, nothing happens. It doesn't compute my click and when I go to the fb page, it still shows that i didn't "like" the page.
Any ideas how to solve this?
I don't know what else to try, but I expect that when I click on the button on my domain, it will compute my like to the page in facebook.

is it a european region issue?
